# Python pyplot syntax error

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
def Prediction2():
    df = TCTDBt
    df = df.sort_values('time')
    print df
    plt.figure(figsize = (18,9))
    plt.plot(range(df.shape[0]),(df['price'])
    plt.xticks(range(0,df.shape[0],100),(df['time'].loc[::100],rotation=45)
    plt.xlabel('time',fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('Price',fontsize=18)
    plt.show()
```

Hey guys im getting a syntax error on the 7th line but have tried changing about every thing i can think of anyone see whats wrong?

```
def Prediction2():
    df = TCTDBt
    df = df.sort_values('time')
    print df
    plt.figure(figsize = (18,9))
    plt.plot(range(df.shape[0]),(df['price']))
    plt.xticks(range(0,df.shape[0],100),(df['time'].loc[::100],rotation=45))
    plt.xlabel('time',fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('Price',fontsize=18)
    plt.show()
```

think i applied your fixed still getting the syntax error

Comment: missing a bracket in this line `plt.plot(range(df.shape[0]),(df['price'])` and in the next too

Comment: @PRMoureu Is right but also this line `plt.xticks(range(0,df.shape[0],100),(df['time'].loc[::100],rotation=45)` is missing a parentheses at the end

Comment: ah didnt even see that fixed that still getting a syntax error on the .xticks line however

Comment: @Ben Saw my comment?

Comment: updated top post

Comment: where is the error now ?

Comment: the .xticks line is still getting invalid syntax

Comment: the parameter `rotation=45` is not at the good place

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.xticks(range(0,df.shape[0],100),df['time'].loc[::100],rotation=45)
```

was the syntax required for that line @PRMoureu was right about the line above also missing a bracket